# CRUD - Angular 2 cannot update

Tags: angular, api, mean-stack, angular2-forms

I am currently trying to update a product in our DB that is uploaded to Heroku. But the form isn't working when submitting. The main goal is to update the product with the id:

> 5a1fe407bc970801902c6c74

app.component.html:

```
<form>
<b>You will now edit product with ID: 5a1fe407bc970801902c6c74</b><br>
Name:
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]= "product_name" placeholder="{{ product_name}}" name="product_name"><br>
Description
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]= "product_description" placeholder="{{ product_description}}" name="product_description"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

index.js

```
app.put('/example', function(req, res)  {
    Product.findByIdAndUpdate("5a1fe407bc970801902c6c74", { $set: req.body }, { new: true }, function (err, product) {
        res.send(product);
    });
});
```

app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
this.shopService.getAll()
    .subscribe(data => this.categories = data);

    this.shopService.getOne()
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.product_name = data.name;
      this.product_description = data.description;
    });
  }
}
```

shop.service.ts

```
  updateOne(product_name: string, product_description: string) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let data = {
      name: product_name,
      description: product_description
    };

  return this.http
  .put('/example', JSON.stringify(data), {headers: headers})
  .map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.put(` returns a cold observable. It won't do anything if you don't `subscribe(` to it i think...